# Analyze a video's pixel data in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to do some video analysis on my PC but I'd like to see if I can do something similar in the browser using Flash.

Does Flash offer any way to take a video file as input, crack it open, and get access to the pixel data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a Video Player (there are default components for this) and draw the video player into a BitmapData.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoWidth, heightHeight);
bitmapData.draw(videoPlayer);
trace(bitmapData.getPixel(123, 321));
```

This should print the pixel at 123, 321.